# Condition based on time in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table "shift plan" with a column that calculates the overtime (working hours after 8 hours of a regular shift).

The cells in the column H get their data by a formula.

For example

```
=H160=IF($G197>TIMEVALUE("08:00");$G197-TIMEVALUE("08:00");"00:00")
```

I have written VBA code to highlight by color every cell containing a value not equal to 00:00.

I put the following code in a module:

```vb
Sub ColorChange()

    Debug.Print ;

    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim CommentValue As Variant
    Dim CommentRange As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set CommentRange = ws.Range("H2:H366")
    
    For Each xCell In CommentRange
    
        On Error Resume Next ' Ignore errors temporarily
      
        If IsDate(xCell.value) Then ' Check if the cell value is a valid date/time
            CommentValue = xCell.value
          
            Select Case Format(CommentValue, "hh:mm")
            
                Case "00:00"
                    xCell.Font.Bold = Bold
                    xCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                          
                Case "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00"
                    xCell.Font.Bold = True
                    xCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 128, 0) ' Green
      
            End Select
       
        Else
            Debug.Print "Invalid Date/Time: " & xCell.value & xCell.Address
            Debug.Print "Error Message: " & Err.Description
            
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling
    Next xCell

End Sub
```

I am only interested in highlighting every cell not equal to 00:00.

I added `Case "00:00` to verify if the code is running as nothing happened for the other conditions. With that code every cell containing the value 00:00 is changed to bold while the other remain unchanged.

The cells are all formatted `hh:mm`

When I put the values manually in another column, it seems to work. I guess the problem comes from the formula in the column H? But, in that case why does it work for the value "00:00"?

Comment: Why are you ignoring errors and what error do you get if you `On Error Goto 0`?

Comment: Also try to not have on error resume next in a loop. Especially since you turn off errors at the first step of the loop then turn them back on at the last step. You could just leave them off by moving it up above the loop. But in this case I agree with Peter, lets see what errors on do first.

Comment: `Debug.Print Format(CommentValue, "hh:mm")` would be very useful here.

Comment: I'm not sure `Format()` is needed, what is CommentValue?

Comment: Did you record the macro or did you hand-write it?

Comment: `Select Case xcell.Value: Case Is <>0: ...`.

Comment: Try `Select Case xCell.Text`

Comment: I didn't pay attention to the error handling as I was trying different solutions. I will try xCell.Value / xCell.Text

Comment: Could you use Conditional Formatting?  _Cell Value between =TIMEVALUE("01:00") and =TIMEVALUE("04:00")_

Comment: I wasn't aware of using timevalue in conditional formatting. Keep you posted. Thx everybody

Comment: Well that worked just fine  Thx ☝️

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub ColorChange()

Dim xCell As Range
Dim CommentValue As Variant
Dim CommentRange As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set CommentRange = ws.Range("H2:H366")

For Each xCell In CommentRange

    On Error Resume Next ' Ignore errors temporarily
    
    If IsDate(xCell.Value) Then ' Check if the cell value is a valid date/time
        CommentValue = xCell.Value
      
        Select Case Format(CommentValue, "hh:mm")
        
            Case "00:00"
                xCell.Font.Bold = True ' Bold should be set to True, not a variable named Bold
                xCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                      
            Case "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00"
                xCell.Font.Bold = True
                xCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 128, 0) ' Green
  
        End Select
   
    Else
        Debug.Print "Invalid Date/Time: " & xCell.Value & " in cell " & xCell.Address
        Debug.Print "Error Message: " & Err.Description
    
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling
Next xCell
```

End Sub